# css3 mobile media queries

Tags: css

I have different views on portrait and landscape

```
    /* portrait ----------- */
    @media only screen 
    and (max-width : 320px) {
      body{
         padding:20px;
        }
    }


  /* landscape----------- */
      @media only screen 
    and (min-width : 321px) {
     body
        {
        padding:60px;
        }
    }
  /* webpage----------- */
       body
            {
            padding:0px;
            }
```

however, landscape css effects on webpage view. how do I spilt webpage up? 
I tried to make another media query on webpage, but it didnt work.
also I tried `(min-device-width : 321px)` for devices only, but it doesnt work

Comment: [css expanding based on portrait or landscape screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858466/css-expanding-based-on-portrait-or-landscape-screen-size)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this article](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/), the media query spec includes orientation detection. It should look something like this:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width:321px) {
    foo {
        padding:60px;
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) and (max-width:320px) {
    foo {
        padding:20px;
    }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: just tried! the same as I used queries. I think I need to set max-width .

Comment: This does set `max-width`. Is it possible that you're trying to use this in a browser which requires prefixes, while not using prefixes?

Comment: Let me spare you the trouble of adding prefixes to everything. Here's [a tiny JavaScript, Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/), which you include on any pages with links to prefix-requiring CSS properties. It'll save you time and trouble in the long run.