# Rotate image and stick it to top left corner

Tags: html, css

I have simple html markup with just an `img` tag in it

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img1.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Image is 800px in width and 1400px in height. So it's portrait oriented and I need to rotate it and stick it to top left corner of page.
Also as it would be 1400px in width now I would need to limit it to 100% of A4 page if possible

Comment: firstly a A4 page has dimensions in cm your html,body css needs to set in the same instead of px for accuracy. Secondly you may not need to rotate the image (i assume you want this either for tablets or printing) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858466/css-expanding-based-on-portrait-or-landscape-screen-size

Comment: Do you need teh image for anything else?  I would suggest rotating it with an image editor or paint or something, then importing and using the image...instead of wasting resources rotating the image using CSS.  Then you could just absolutely position it inside a div that is 100% wide and make it a max-width of 100%.

Comment: curious about the usecase for this...it seems an odd way to go about it. Why not just edit the image?

Comment: If you have access to Windows Photo Viewer or any graphic editing programs, why not rotate the image in those and save yourself the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to edit the actual image file in your case, however you can rotate an element by using the CSS3 transform property. To get it at the top of the page you could use a negative top margin. To bring it further right onto the page use a positive left margin.

```
img{ 
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    margin-top:-300px;
    margin-left:300px;
}
```