# Mobile media queries in landscape mode?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

My mobile media queries dont work in landscape mode, maybe I am not displaying `media only screen` right. I am not using any frameworks , just regular CSS...

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

this is what I have right now

```
@media (min-width : 319px) and (max-width: 480px){
    //css here
}
```

not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a useful attribute/function in CSS called `orientation` which has two options:

1. Landscape
2. Portrait

And this is how you can use it:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* Your CSS Here*/
}
```

To attach the screen max and min width you can do something like this:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
and (min-device-width: 319px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   /* Your CSS Here*/
}
```

See this reference: [css expanding based on portrait or landscape screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858466/css-expanding-based-on-portrait-or-landscape-screen-size) and also a documentation about the `@media` queries on this page: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices

I hope this will help you :-)

Comment: thanks...what about (min-width : 319px) or (max-width: 480px), how do I know whats my min and max ?

Comment: @Ris You can sum it up like you already did with the min and max width. There is an helpfull documentation about it, maybe you want to see it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this combination of media-query + viewport height ?

```
video {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
   video {
      height: calc(100vh - 110px);
   }
}
```

100vh = 100% of your viewport height.

110px is the height of my navigation bar, (just need to adapt it to your dimensions)